# Replace double quotes with blank

Tags: php, json, preg-replace, str-replace, double-quotes

So I am collecting data from a JSON feed and saving some of them into an array. This one particular item `$result['issuer']` contains our customers' names. I guess this name can contain any
characters, but so far I have only seen with **comma** (,) like: *San Marino Unif Sch Dist, CA GO* ...and because of this **comma** i'm using `json_encode` But now I can't seem to get rid of the double quotes around the names. I am not sure what I am doing wrong, but tried so many different ways without any luck :(

```
if($auction != false)
{   
  $auction = json_decode($auction, TRUE);

 foreach($auction['recent_results'] as $result)
 {
    // grab today's data for all auction types 
    if ($result['end_date'] === $GLOBALS["yesterday"]) 
    {
        $json_string = json_encode($result['issuer']);
        //$json_string = $result['issuer'];
        //$json_string = str_replace('/"([^"]+)"\s*:\s*/', '$1:', $json_string);
        $json_string = str_replace("\"", "", $json_string);
        //$json_string = str_replace(array('\'', '"'), '', $json_string);

        //$json_string = preg_replace("/[^a-zA-Z0-9 ,]+/", "", html_entity_decode($result['issuer'])); //this one kind of works, but not letting me escape the COMMA at the end
        //$json_string = preg_replace('/"([^"]+)"\s*:\s*/', '$1:', $json_string);

        $pastAuction[] = array("ISSUER" => $json_string, "TYPE" => $result['issue_type'], "TERM" => $result['term'], "FINAL YIELD" => $result['closing_yield']."%", "CLOSING DATE" => $result['end_date']);         
    }
  }
}
```

Right now the name is getting saved as either...

- `"San Marino Unif Sch Dist, CA GO"`
- or in 2 different fields like `San Marino Unif Sch Dist` & `CA GO`

But I want to save it like: `San Marino Unif Sch Dist, CA GO`
Please help!!!

Comment: That's because you're encoding the string as JSON! If PHP sees just a string, it converts it to a JSON fragment, which is a string wrapped in double quotes and with the proper escapes (" becomes \")

Comment: I am still pretty new at this. The reason i did the encoding because i did this `$auction = json_decode($auction, TRUE);` earlier. Would you mind show me other ways to do it then? Thanks

Comment: Why are you json_encode()-ing the string, in the first place?

Comment: if i don't do that then the name is getting break into 2 parts because of the comma (,). Like `San Marino Unif Sch Dist` & `CA GO`

Comment: Can I see your entire code? How are you using $json_string?

Comment: I posted it. Hope that't enough. Thanks!

Comment: **Do not** json_encode() in cases other than _encoding to JSON_. This is simply bad programming. Read the docs about [str_replace](http://en.php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php), [preg_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) and others, for stripping/changing the comma you don't want.